# Combine hashes with arrays for some keys

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am relatively new with perl and I have been stuck with this for some days. Hope you can help me.

I work with two files that I will simplify as I had to process them beforehand:

`file_one` with a list of `names` (name_1, name_2, name_3...) and `numbers` (number_1, number_2, number_3...) respectively associated

And `file_two` with a list of `numbers` (number_2 and number_6) and `items` (item_a, item_b associated with number_2, and item_b,item_c associated with number_6)

My idea was to make hashes of both files and combine them. The point I get stuck is when I need to join the list of items into the hash (hash of an array) and then use it. So the first hash works fine, but the second has the issue.

I tried using `push (@{ $hash2{$numbers} }, $items)`, but then I do not know how to combine it with the other because of the reference I used.

The final task would be to compare two names in order to get which items they share. And it would be great if it could be done just with perl and using no modules if possible.

Thank you very much

Comment: Pasting a snippet of the two files would be very useful to understanding the problem. No need for fancy formatting, just highlight it and hit `{}` for a code sample.

Comment: An example is always better than a description, as long as you show a full set of cases. *"file_one with a list of names (name_1, name_2, name_3...) and numbers (number_1, number_2, number_3...) associated respectively"* **Schwern**, below, seems fairly confident in his interpretation of your words, but I have my doubts

Comment: There is no way to construct a table in markdown. The best option would be to copy and paste several lines of your data files into your question. If you indent all of those lines by four spaces (which you can do by selecting all the lines and hitting *Ctrl-K*) then they will be displayed pre-formatted.

Comment: Why no modules?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have this:

```
foo => 1
bar => 2
baz => 3
```

Then you have:

```
2 => a, b
3 => b, c
```

And you want to know what items `bar` and `baz` share (for example).

One option is to put them into two tables in a [SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite) database and use SQL. This can be the simplest, most flexible, and most performant way to deal with relational data like this. Especially if there's a lot of it, and especially if you want to do a lot of different searches on it. This avoids having to write a bunch of custom code and a probably increasingly complicated data structure.

---

Doing it in Perl, here's a sketch.

First, read in the second file, which contains the leaves (the items don't point to anything else), into a hash of arrays. You wind up with a structure like:

```
$nums2items{2} = [qw(a, b)];
```

Then read in the first file into a hash but instead of storing the numbers as values, store what `%nums2items` references.

```
$names2items{foo} = $nums2items{1};
```

Now if you want to check if `bar` and `baz` share anything, you can get the arrays and find their intersection with [Array::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Utils).

```
use Array::Utils qw(intersect);

print join ", ", intersect( @{$names2items{bar}}, @{$names2items{baz}});
```

If you're going to do this a lot, and the order of the items does not matter, it is more efficient to store the items as a hash. This avoids having to sort and compare two lists. It's what `intersect` does anyway, turns one list into a hash (or a set) and compares it against the other list.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my %nums2items = (
    2   => { a => 1, b => 1,         d => 1 },
    3   => {         b => 1, c => 1, d => 1, e => 1 },
);
my %names2nums = (
    bar => $nums2items{2},
    baz => $nums2items{3}
);

# Take the intersection in O(n) time.
say join ", ", grep { $names2nums{bar}{$_} } keys %{$names2nums{baz}};
```

Using a hash like that, where the key is the thing and the value is 1, is a very common and efficient way of representing a set.

Or you can use the [Set::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::Tiny) module. It's very straight forward. If you want to learn how to work with sets in Perl, I highly recommend reading its source.

Comment: Yes, basically your interpretation is correct, thank you for answering. But I would need to use only perl for this, and also no modules, as I would like to learn how to do it... I mean of course if it is possible

Comment: @Gutinu of course that's possible. The people who wrote Array::Utils did it. Read the source of that to see how that's done.

Comment: @Gutinu "I don't want to/can't use modules" raises a red flag for Perl programmers. They're so important, and many places have misguided "no CPAN modules" policies. For learning what I would suggest is to do it long hand, then do it with modules, then do it with SQLite. That covers "I want to try writing it myself" and also "this is how you'd do it for production with a real amount of data". Try writing `intersect` yourself, then [peek inside Array::Utils](https://metacpan.org/source/ZMIJ/Array-Utils-0.5/Utils.pm) to see how they did it.

Comment: @Gutinu I highly recommend you [read the source of Set::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/source/TRENDELS/Set-Tiny-0.04/lib/Set/Tiny.pm) to see how one works efficiently with sets in Perl. It's very straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment to Schwern it appears you files look something like this:

```
foo, 1
bar, 2
biz, 3
bas, 4
```

and

```
1, jacks blue horse
2, the green horse
3, jacks
4, bing
```

and you are successfully reading them into two hashes with values before the comma as the key and that after as the value.  Now you what to take the words pair wise and print out words they have in common.  You don't want to use any modules but do it in raw Perl.

First, why isn't the second an array of arrays instead of a hash if it is numerically keyed?

Second, why are you merging them?  Why not use nested loops:

```
my @key_list = keys %hash_1;
while ( @key_list )
   {
   my $curr_key = shift @key_list;
   for my $next_key ( @key_list )
      {
      my @curr_list = @{$hash_2{$hash_1{$curr_key}}};
      my @next_list = @{$hash_2{$hash_1{$next_key}}};
      while ( @curr_list )
         {
         my $curr_word = shift @curr_list;
         for my $next_word ( @next_list )
            {
            print "$curr_key and $next_key share $curr_word\n"
               if $curr_word eq $next_word;
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

It's a bit brute force but it would get the job done.  Instead you could use the excellent Set:: modules.  Part of knowing and using a modern language like Perl or C++ well is knowing the standard and common libraries and using them.

Comment: "*Why not use nested loops?*" The answer is because it's highly inefficient and very difficult to understand *four* nested loops. Your loop is at least `O(n!)` and probably worse, meaning as the list of keys doubles your runtime will quadruple. Finally, dereferencing all the lists makes copies of each of them increasing memory usage. Or you're being very clever and illustrating why one should use modules rather than write it yourself. :)

Comment: I am well aware of the inefficiency but the OP has indicated he wishes to avoid using modules which leaves few methods beyond brute force.  I much prefer your Arrays::Utils method to this.  I would tend to use Set::Scalar's intersection.  That's why at the end I pointed out the importance of knowing and using available modules.

Comment: I added to my answer an O(n) solution using hashes as sets. Have a look.